# How to pass data from database to controller and then show in view in select option tag. ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to get data from the database which i am able to do but i cant seem to pass it to the view's select option tag in html.

I've tried using a string and pasing it but it just passes the first value. havent been able to pass it through a string array either

```
public ActionResult GetDetails()
{
    SqlConnection con;
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
    con = new SqlConnection(constr);
    con.Open();
    string sqlCommand = "SELECT *FROM cityname";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCommand, con);
    SqlDataReader read;

    read = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    List<string> str = new List<string>();

    while(read.Read())
    {
        str.Add(read.GetValue(1).ToString());
    }

    ViewBag.mydata = str;

    return View();
}
```

I want to be able to show it in this

```
<select class="mdb-select md-form" id="PersonCity" name="PersonCountry" onchange="run1();">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your Country</option>
    <option value='$country_name'>$country_name</option>
```

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20387205/asp-net-mvc-selectlist-in-viewmodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20387205/asp-net-mvc-selectlist-in-viewmodel) ?

Comment: I cant iterate viewbags. I wanna be able to send it to the the selectoption in html and then iterate it through javascript

Comment: how about this? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836428/asp-net-mvc-return-json-result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836428/asp-net-mvc-return-json-result)

Comment: Why don't you use the helper method `@Html.DropDownListFor()`?

Comment: I dont know how to use helper methods. im new to mvc and asp.net

Comment: return View(str);  then use your Model to iterate using foreach loop

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace your html for this

```
@Html.DropDownList("value", new SelectList(ViewBag.mydata))
```